# UDP Socket Connection - Broadcast/Listen Messages

Tags: android, sockets, udp, android-networking

I am able to create UDP socket communication if I have the IP address of the server, But is it possible that I just broadcast message on a port from one device (Server) and let all device (Client) in same network can listen the broadcast and reply?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can by setting ip address 255.255.255.255 i think

Edited: 
actually you should set ip address all ones for host name only so for example if your ip address is 
192.168.0.100 than the ip address should be 192.168.255.255 for broadcasting

Comment: It should be all ones in the host part of the netmask. Not all IP addresses are class B.